# Error when trying to code Battleship game

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and as a exercise I want to code the game Battleship. I currently use Jupyter Notebook. So I'll try to explain as detailed as possible what I did. I could probably code it way more simple, but with what I know of python at this point this was logical for me. The user texts are in dutch, but coding I did in English.
This is just the start of the whole code, but I want to know why a certain error occurs (see bottom of this post). If the code is too messy or its not understandable, please let me know, then I'll try to specify it. Thanks :)

```
gamehidden_pl1 = ['#']+[' ']*100
list_with_coords = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8','C9','C10','D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','D9','D10','E1','E2','E3','E4','E5','E6','E7','E8','E9','E10','F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10','G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6','G7','G8','G9','G10','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8','H9','H10','I1','I2','I3','I4','I5','I6','I7','I8','I9','I10','J1','J2','J3','J4','J5','J6','J7','J8','J9','J10']
```

First I made a function to display the game board:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def game_board_hidden(board):
    clear_output()
    
    print("   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 1 | "+board[1]+" | "+board[2]+" | "+board[3]+" | "+board[4]+" | "+board[5]+" | "+board[6]+" | "+board[7]+" | "+board[8]+" | "+board[9]+" | "+board[10]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 2 | "+board[11]+" | "+board[12]+" | "+board[13]+" | "+board[14]+" | "+board[15]+" | "+board[16]+" | "+board[17]+" | "+board[18]+" | "+board[19]+" | "+board[20]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 3 | "+board[21]+" | "+board[22]+" | "+board[23]+" | "+board[24]+" | "+board[25]+" | "+board[26]+" | "+board[27]+" | "+board[28]+" | "+board[29]+" | "+board[30]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 4 | "+board[31]+" | "+board[32]+" | "+board[33]+" | "+board[34]+" | "+board[35]+" | "+board[36]+" | "+board[37]+" | "+board[38]+" | "+board[39]+" | "+board[40]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 5 | "+board[41]+" | "+board[42]+" | "+board[43]+" | "+board[44]+" | "+board[45]+" | "+board[46]+" | "+board[47]+" | "+board[48]+" | "+board[49]+" | "+board[50]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 6 | "+board[51]+" | "+board[52]+" | "+board[53]+" | "+board[54]+" | "+board[55]+" | "+board[56]+" | "+board[57]+" | "+board[58]+" | "+board[59]+" | "+board[60]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 7 | "+board[61]+" | "+board[62]+" | "+board[63]+" | "+board[64]+" | "+board[65]+" | "+board[66]+" | "+board[67]+" | "+board[68]+" | "+board[69]+" | "+board[70]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 8 | "+board[71]+" | "+board[72]+" | "+board[73]+" | "+board[74]+" | "+board[75]+" | "+board[76]+" | "+board[77]+" | "+board[78]+" | "+board[79]+" | "+board[80]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print(" 9 | "+board[81]+" | "+board[82]+" | "+board[83]+" | "+board[84]+" | "+board[85]+" | "+board[86]+" | "+board[87]+" | "+board[88]+" | "+board[89]+" | "+board[90]+" |")
    print("---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")
    print("10 | "+board[91]+" | "+board[92]+" | "+board[93]+" | "+board[94]+" | "+board[95]+" | "+board[96]+" | "+board[97]+" | "+board[98]+" | "+board[99]+" | "+board[100]+" |")
```

Then I started to make a function that lets the player choose a location to place their smallest boats (length of 2). First it asks the initial position and then it asks if the player wants it to face up, down, left or right on the board.

```
def place_two_schip_pl1(list_with_coords):
    
    new_coords = '#'
    
    coords_place_ship = input("Waar wil je jouw Patrouilleschip neerzetten (2)? ").upper()
    coords_to_index(coords_place_ship,new_coords)
    
    while coords_place_ship not in list_with_coords:
        print("Deze coordinaten zijn niet juist")
        coords_place_ship = input("Waar wil je jouw Patrouilleschip neerzetten (2)? ").upper()
        coords_to_index(coords_place_ship,new_coords)
        
    while gamehidden_pl1[new_coords] == 'X':
        print("Deze coordinaten zijn al in gebruik door een ander schip!")
        coords_place_ship = input("Waar wil je jouw Patrouilleschip neerzetten (lengte 2) Player 1? ").upper():
            coords_to_index(coords_place_ship,new_coords)
        
    gamehidden_pl1[new_coords].replace('X')
    
    direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
    
    while direction_ship == 'L' or direction_ship == 'LEFT':
        if coords_place_ship == 'A1' or coords_place_ship == 'A2' or coords_place_ship == 'A3' or coords_place_ship == 'A4' or coords_place_ship == 'A5' or coords_place_ship == 'A6' or coords_place_ship == 'A7' or coords_place_ship == 'A8' or coords_place_ship == 'A9' or coords_place_ship == 'A10':
            print("Dat is niet mogelijk")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        elif gamehidden_pl1[new_coords-1] == 'X':
            print("Deze locatie is al bezet door een ander schip!")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        gamehidden_pl1[new_coords-1].replace('X')
        
        
    while direction_ship == 'R' or direction_ship == 'RIGHT':
        if coords_place_ship == 'J1' or coords_place_ship == 'J2' or coords_place_ship == 'J3' or coords_place_ship == 'J4' or coords_place_ship == 'J5' or coords_place_ship == 'J6' or coords_place_ship == 'J7' or coords_place_ship == 'J8' or coords_place_ship == 'J9' or coords_place_ship == 'J10':
            print("Dat is niet mogelijk")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        elif gamehidden_pl1[new_coords+1] == 'X':
            print("Deze locatie is al bezet door een ander schip!")
            direction_schip = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        gamehidden_pl1[new_coords+1].replace('X')
        
    
    while direction_ship == 'U' or direction_ship == 'UP':
        if coords_place_ship == 'A1' or coords_place_ship == 'B1' or coords_place_ship == 'C1' or coords_place_ship == 'D1' or coords_place_ship == 'E1' or coords_place_ship == 'F1' or coords_place_ship == 'G1' or coords_place_ship == 'H1' or coords_place_ship == 'I1' or coords_place_ship == 'J1':
            print("Dat is niet mogelijk")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        elif gamehidden_pl1[new_coords-10] == 'X':
            print("Deze locatie is al bezet door een ander schip!")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        gamehidden_pl1[new_coords-10].replace('X')
        
    while direction_ship == 'U' or direction_ship == 'UNDER':
        if coords_place_ship == 'A10' or coords_place_ship == 'B10' or coords_place_ship == 'C10' or coords_place_ship == 'D10' or coords_place_ship == 'E10' or coords_place_ship == 'F10' or coords_place_ship == 'G10' or coords_place_ship == 'H10' or coords_place_ship == 'I10' or coords_place_ship == 'J10':
            print("Dat is niet mogelijk")
            direction_ship = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        elif gamehidden_pl1[new_coords+10] == 'X':
            print("Deze locatie is al bezet door een ander schip!")
            direction_schip = input("Welke richting op wil je boot op plaatsen: Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D)? ").upper()
            
        gamehidden_pl1[new_coords+10].replace('X')
```

And I made this function that translates the users input coordinates into the correct index position of the hidden game board (gamehidden_pl1) to place initial position of the boat there:

```
def coords_to_index(coords,new_coords):

if coords == "A1":
    new_coords = 1
    
if coords == "A2":
    new_coords = 2
    
if coords == "A3":
    new_coords = 3
    
if coords == "A4":
    new_coords = 4
    
if coords == "A5":
    new_coords = 5
    
if coords == "A6":
    new_coords = 6
    
if coords == "A7":
    new_coords = 7
    
if coords == "A8":
    new_coords = 8
    
if coords == "A9":
    new_coords = 9
    
if coords == "A10":
    new_coords = 10
    
if coords == "B1":
    new_coords = 11
    
if coords == "B2":
    new_coords = 12
    
if coords == "B3":
    new_coords = 13
    
if coords == "B4":
    new_coords = 14
    
if coords == "B5":
    new_coords = 15
    
if coords == "B6":
    new_coords = 16
    
if coords == "B7":
    new_coords = 17
    
if coords == "B8":
    new_coords = 18
    
if coords == "B9":
    new_coords = 19
    
if coords == "B10":
    new_coords = 20
    
if coords == "C1":
    new_coords = 21
    
if coords == "C2":
    new_coords = 22
    
if coords == "C3":
    new_coords = 23
    
if coords == "C4":
    new_coords = 24
    
if coords == "C5":
    new_coords = 25
    
if coords == "C6":
    new_coords = 26
    
if coords == "C7":
    new_coords = 27
    
if coords == "C8":
    new_coords = 28
    
if coords == "C9":
    new_coords = 29
    
if coords == "C10":
    new_coords = 30
    
if coords == "D1":
    new_coords = 31
    
if coords == "D2":
    new_coords = 32
    
if coords == "D3":
    new_coords = 33
    
if coords == "D4":
    new_coords = 34
    
if coords == "D5":
    new_coords = 35
    
if coords == "D6":
    new_coords = 36
    
if coords == "D7":
    new_coords = 37
    
if coords == "D8":
    new_coords = 38
    
if coords == "D9":
    new_coords = 39
    
if coords == "D10":
    new_coords = 40
    
if coords == "E1":
    new_coords = 41
    
if coords == "E2":
    new_coords = 42
    
if coords == "E3":
    new_coords = 43
    
if coords == "E4":
    new_coords = 44
    
if coords == "E5":
    new_coords = 45
    
if coords == "E6":
    new_coords = 46
    
if coords == "E7":
    new_coords = 47
    
if coords == "E8":
    new_coords = 48
    
if coords == "E9":
    new_coords = 49
    
if coords == "E10":
    new_coords = 50
    
if coords == "F1":
    new_coords = 51
    
if coords == "F2":
    new_coords = 52
    
if coords == "F3":
    new_coords = 53
    
if coords == "F4":
    new_coords = 54
    
if coords == "F5":
    new_coords = 55
    
if coords == "F6":
    new_coords = 56
    
if coords == "F7":
    new_coords = 57
    
if coords == "F8":
    new_coords = 58
    
if coords == "F9":
    new_coords = 59
    
if coords == "F10":
    new_coords = 60
    
if coords == "G1":
    new_coords = 61
    
if coords == "G2":
    new_coords = 62
    
if coords == "G3":
    new_coords = 63
    
if coords == "G4":
    new_coords = 64
    
if coords == "G5":
    new_coords = 65
    
if coords == "G6":
    new_coords = 66
    
if coords == "G7":
    new_coords = 67
    
if coords == "G8":
    new_coords = 68
    
if coords == "G9":
    new_coords = 69
    
if coords == "G10":
    new_coords = 70
    
if coords == "H1":
    new_coords = 71
    
if coords == "H2":
    new_coords = 72
    
if coords == "H3":
    new_coords = 73
    
if coords == "H4":
    new_coords = 74
    
if coords == "H5":
    new_coords = 75
    
if coords == "H6":
    new_coords = 76
    
if coords == "H7":
    new_coords = 77
    
if coords == "H8":
    new_coords = 78
    
if coords == "H9":
    new_coords = 79
    
if coords == "H10":
    new_coords = 80
    
if coords == "I1":
    new_coords = 81
    
if coords == "I2":
    new_coords = 82
    
if coords == "I3":
    new_coords = 83
    
if coords == "I4":
    new_coords = 84
    
if coords == "I5":
    new_coords = 85
    
if coords == "I6":
    new_coords = 86
    
if coords == "I7":
    new_coords = 87
    
if coords == "I8":
    new_coords = 88
    
if coords == "I9":
    new_coords = 89
    
if coords == "I10":
    new_coords = 90
    
if coords == "J1":
    new_coords = 91
    
if coords == "J2":
    new_coords = 92
    
if coords == "J3":
    new_coords = 93
    
if coords == "J4":
    new_coords = 94
    
if coords == "J5":
    new_coords = 95
    
if coords == "J6":
    new_coords = 96
    
if coords == "J7":
    new_coords = 97
    
if coords == "J8":
    new_coords = 98
    
if coords == "J9":
    new_coords = 99
    
if coords == "J10":
    new_coords = 100
```

But I get a error when I run this:

```
game_board_hidden(gamehidden_pl1)
place_two_schip_pl1(list_with_coords)
game_board_hidden(gamehidden_pl1)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/vb/0qhzrwmn6kggwg9bw7t3gg2m0000gs/T/ipykernel_3322/1993116893.py in 
<module>
      1 game_board_visible(gamehidden_pl1)
----> 2 place_two_schip_pl1(list_with_coords)
      3 game_board_visible(gamehidden_pl1)

/var/folders/vb/0qhzrwmn6kggwg9bw7t3gg2m0000gs/T/ipykernel_3322/1651108048.py in 
place_two_schip_pl1(list_with_coords)
     11         coords_to_index(coords_place_ship,new_coords)
     12 
---> 13     while gamehidden_pl1[new_coords] == 'X':
     14         print("Deze coordinaten zijn al in gebruik door een ander schip!")
     15         coords_place_ship = input("Waar wil je jouw Patrouilleschip 
neerzetten (lengte 2) Player 1? ").upper()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So I know that that means that my new_coords aren't translated to an integer with the function I made (coords_to_index), because I tested it. The new_coords stay '#', but why doesn't it get translated to the correct number?

Hopefully someone will be able to answer this mess haha, thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend reading up on `for` loops to eliminate a lot of that repetition. Also you probably want your board cells to be a list of lists, rather than a single list. Each list would be a row (or a column, if you want to do it that way).

Comment: Arguments of functions are transferred by value. This means that on call of "coords_to_index" the **value** (a reference to a string) of "new_coords" is copied to a **different** local variable of same name in "coords_to_index" function. Changes to this variable don't affect the other variable.

Comment: Hey there! Editing questions here on Stack Overflow is for clarifying or otherwise improving the question. Please don't replace it with a message about it being solved. But do consider accepting one of the answers by clicking its checkmark. (Once you have 15 rep, you can upvote too.)

Answer (score 0):

That is way to much irrelevant information.

It seems like you could be passing `new_coords` to `coords_to_index` without changing `new_coords`.

Try returning a value from `coords_to_index` like this

```
def coords_to_index(coords_place_ship):
  new_coords = '#'

  //current code definition here

  return new_coords
```

Then you call it like `new_coords = coords_to_index(coords_place_ship)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with passing arguments to a function in Python.
In this case the variable `new_coords` is copied to variable coord. So the change will be not propagated backt to `main` function.

```py
def main():
    new_coords = "#"
    get_index_from_coord(new_coord)
    print(new_coord)
    
def get_index_from_coord(coord):
    if coord == "#":
        coord = 1
    coord = 2

main()

Output: "#"
```

I would rewrite your code in this way:

```py
def main():
    new_coords = "#"
    new_coords = get_index_from_coord(new_coord)
    print(new_coord)
    
def get_index_from_coord(coord):
    if coord == "#":
        return coord = 1
    return coord = 2

main()

Output: "1"
```